# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Users` where `` = meco@mailinator

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried to create a new tenent but through the error of

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Users` where `` = meco@mailinator.com".

but I created all required columns in the database users table.

***`create.blade.php`***

```
<form action="{{route('tenants.store')}}" method="POST">

    @csrf
    <!-- name input field -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name"
                value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

            @error('name')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- email input field -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email"
                value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

            @error('email')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- domain Input Field -->
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="domain" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Domain') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="domain" type="text" class="form-control @error('domain') is-invalid @enderror" name="domain"
                value="{{ old('domain') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

            @error('domain')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {{ __('Save Tenant') }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

***storeTenantRequest.php***

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StoreTenantRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'email|required|unique:Users,',
            'domain' => 'required|unique:users',
        ];
    }
}
```

***TenentController***

```
 public function store(StoreTenantRequest $request)
    {

       User::create($request->validated() + ['role_id'=> 2, 'password'=>'secreat']);
       return redirect()->route('tenants.index');
    }
```

***web.php***

```
Route::resource('tenants',TenantController::class);
```

Comment: Do you have a select query in your model ?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error as you are not using unique validation properly so it's taking column name as blank to check unique email. Please use the below solution.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'domain' => 'required|unique:users',
    ];
}
```